# Google Docs auto bold formatting

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting

How to automatically make any sentence starting with `Q:` and ending with `?` bold?

For example if `Q: Who does the program plan?` is typed in a Google Doc it should turn bold. I am looking at options like typing asterisks before and after the statement to make it bold. Probably many would suggest using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, but using the replace function I can just replace `Q` with `*Q` to bold the entire sentence, closing it with `Q*`.